# filtering a published chart Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-visualization

I have a [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nab2xSdjk-EqNvi3i-40F7xwowSNdW-BlnKaERxvTFQ/edit?usp=sharing) with a chart and a slicer for filtering
I have published the sheet with the chart
[Published Chart](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSGJzM3M04R8LMOfB0YI0mJg1c0qqN3O3-vyL9zAon4ZZYLWFtEOV_f8Qp-Xv0YLhr4Nl_h4he4KdJi/pubhtml?gid=1719345790&single=true)

But the slicer does not work on the published sheet

Is there a method of filtering a chart that will work on a published chart?

Thanks

Comment: A published chart is no longer of a data type which is filterable by Sheets methods. [Publishing a chart changes its type to an image format like PNG or SVG, or to PDF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1047436?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Comment: Thanks, Rafa, that's what I thought but I asked to see if there was a way around that